# How can I sort on certain properties of an object in a pre-sorted TreeSet?

Tags: java, sorting, compare, treeset

First of all, thanks for reading!

I have created a custom class `CallLog` with `logId`, `logName`, `logCompany`, ...
These CallLogs are stored within a TreeSet and sorted by `logPriority` and `logDateTime` by default. Now I need to print rapports that are sorted by different values. I've created `abstract class Rapport` with methods like `printByName()` to sort my TreeSet by other values as well.

I'm not supposed to alter the `compareTo()` method of CallLog so I would like to know how to sort my TreeSet using other properties of the `CallLog`.

Comment: You can't sort a `TreeSet`. It's self sorting, so if you intend to change the sortings, use a `List` and one of the numerous ways to sort lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the sorting of an existing `TreeSet`, but you can copy your values to another [temporary] collection sorted differently by using a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). In fact, you don't even have to create a new collection, you could just sort the streamed values as you print them:
E.g.:

```
public class Report {
    private Set<CallLog> calls = // initialized somehow...

    public void printByName() {
        calls.stream()
             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CallLog::logName))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```